# Imagemagick treating each word of my caption as an image

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to create a caption in imagemagick using the following command:

```
convert -background white -fill black -font Agency-FB -size 465x247 caption:'This is a test' test.png
```

And am receiving the following error

```
convert: unable to open image 'is': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3527.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/737.
convert: unable to open image 'a': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3527.
convert: unable to open image 'a': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3527.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/737.
convert: unable to open image 'test'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3527.
convert: unable to open image 'test'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3527.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/737.
```

Meanwhile imagemagick spits out an image that is white with black text, and the correct dimensions, with the text

```
'This
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using Windows? And do you need to use ancient v6 **ImageMagick** for some reason?

Comment: First try using double quotes around your caption instead of single quotes.

Comment: I'm using windows, and I am running v7.1.0-27
I retried the command using magick instead of convert and got the same error, except it tried to open 'is' and then moved on, and the " ' " is no longer there.

Comment: Double quotes fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, changing the command to

```
magick -background white -fill black -font Agency-FB -size 465x247 caption:"This is a test" test.png
```

Using the updated call from v7 of Imagemagick as well as double quotes instead of single quotes fixed the issue entirely.